# Cross-platform technical log-keeping / journalling

Tags: cross-platform, logs, productivity, journal

I like to keep daily logs such as:

**Monday 01-JAN-2000:**

1. Met with person X; discussed organizing some social event.
2. This is an interesting post on making Pitch Decks <*link*>
3. Finished chapter 3 of thesis.

But each line belongs to a separate category/timeline:

1. #WineClub
2. #StartupX
3. #MyPhDthesis

Right now what I'm doing is keeping separate timelines (in the form of google docs for each category) but I would like to have everything in one place, where I can sort/search through them by tags/importance/date/etc or a boolean combination, with all the capabilities of google docs.

Is there a cross-platform tool I can use for this? I am not asking for a diary (there are plenty, but mostly aimed at teenage girls!). I want something more technical.

Comment: Have you investigated google Keep for that?  https://keep.google.com/ - - I'm not too familar with keep, so not suggesting as an answer, but I've heard of other people using it for notes.

Comment: I looked it up, it's more of a fancy sticky-note-type app. It is good for todo lists and grocery lists and reminders etc. I want more of a journal format, something like a [ship logbook](http://discoveringbristol.org.uk/images/sized/images/uploads/slavery/Page_log_book_ship_Lloyd_1722-262x400.jpg) but with tags and search/sorting capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [Red Notebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) might be ideal for your needs:

- Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- #Hashtags
- Format your text bold, italic or underlined
- Insert Images, files and links to websites
- Links and mail addresses are recognized automatically
- Spell Check
- Live-Search
- Automatic saving
- Backup to zip archive
- Templates
- Export the journal to plain text, HTML, Latex or PDF
- The data is stored in plain text files, no database is needed

[image]
[image]

If you need to be able to access your journal from multiple machines then I would suggest picking a cloud storage service that supports all your operating systems and allows you to have a folder that is automatically synced - there are several available - and simply use such a folder for your journal location.

Comment: That's pretty much what I want! Only if it had a better UI design and it was browser-based (pain to port into mac) and kept track of edits I would pay to use it! I'm a bit hesitant to make the switch because it doesn't look like it is well maintained. These are important logs that I can't risk losing/not being able to access at a later date if they get corrupted. Hope Google buys these guys and starts Google Logs or something :)

Comment: @cvb0rg - It is available for Mac, Linux & Windows - the journals are text files and the back-ups are standard zip files so the is 0 chance of not being able to access something later.  If you really need to keep track of edits and be sure of recovery just use git/hg on the logs. As for not maintained - I see about a dozen commits this year and we are not in April - check https://github.com/jendrikseipp/rednotebook/commits/master